# How can I generate this simple repeating texture efficiently inside a GLSL shader?

Tags: math, opengl, image-processing, glsl, shader

I have this sub-pixel texture which is normally 8x8 in size (enlarged version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO3SA.png) and I need to be able to generate this texture within GLSL, without actually using any uploaded textures to the shader itself. I know this is possible because I have seen similar math done for textures like this (http://www.reach3d.net/views.pdf), I'm just not sure how to do it the other way around... in other words, I need to generate the math needed to output this texture within the shader.

EDIT: I forgot to mention a 2nd requirement that I have with the generated data.

In the past when I used regular textures, there were also other operations done before the final color is calculated, which required the sub-pixel texture to be moved up and down one of the axes (as in, first row of the texture moves to the bottom if we are moving "up"). For example I have an image texture with 8 or 9 different sections in it (think tic-tac-toe layout) that need to be composited into a single image, where each section is scaled up to full-screen size and multiplied against a different (full-screen, wrapped) sub-pixel texture (like the 8x8 or 3x9). How would this be accomplished?

An input image looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/owS0e.jpg

And an output (using only the first 8 sections, with the 8x8 texture) should look like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvIZL.jpg

Comment: The linked document doesn't say anything about glsl though. I'm no expert, but if I remember correctly, you do have to jump through some hoops determine the pixel 'coordinates' of the fragment in glsl. Once you've done that, you'd only need to identify a function of x and y that returns the correct color. If performance isn't critical, you could probably do it using conditionals too.

Comment: @Tim Correct, and actually this texture is sensitive to the physical screen coordinate it's being painted on, so I do have gl_FragCoord.xy which should give me exactly which coordinate on the screen it's currently working on. I know the document doesn't mention shaders but I have seen those numbers used in shaders before to generate the pattern, I just can't find the code anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pixel locations to be colored seem to be roots for some Diophantine equations:

```
Red: y== x*3+1 mod 8
Gre: y== x*3+2 mod 8
Blu: y== x*3+3 mod 8
```

The shader gets a `varying vec2 vTexCoord;` as input.

You can premultiply the texture coordinates by 8 and use the integer part of the coordinates. (Disclaimer: don't remember if a cast is enough for float->int conversion in GLSL.)

```
int a=(((int)vTexCoord.x)*3 - ((int)vTexCoord.y)) & 7;
glColor = vec4( (a==1)?1.0:0.0,
                (a==2)?1.0:0.0,
                (a==3)?1.0:0.0, 1.0);
```

**EDIT**

For 3x9 system one has to check for red pixels the condition:

```
     F(x mod 3, y mod 9) == true iff (y=0;x=2), (y=3;x=1), (y=6;x=0)
```

This can be coded exactly as is:

```
 bool is_red = (y==0 && x==2) || (y==3 && x==1) || (y==6 && x==0);
```

But it can be also represented as:

```
 bool is_red   = (x*3-y == 0);  // and following the same logic
 bool is_green = (x*3-y == 1);
 bool is_blue  = (x*3-y == 2);
```

A complete fragment shader using these latter equations would be:

```
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main()
{
    float x = fract(v_texCoord.x * (1.0/3.0));
    float y = fract(v_texCoord.y * (1.0/9.0));
    int xmod3 = (int)(x*3.0);
    int ymod9 = (int)(y*9.0);
    int d = xmod3*3-ymod9;

    gl_FragColor = vec4((d==0)?1.0f:0.0f,
                        (d==1)?1.0f:0.0f,
                        (d==2)?1.0f:0.0f,
                        1.0f);
}
```

Here's a webgl [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrakis/C6sKb/) version that uses shader version 1.0 with restrictions such as no integer modulo, no logical and; and here's for the [second version](http://jsfiddle.net/mrakis/cxtCW/2/).

Comment: GLSL has `floor()` to explicitly request the non-fractional part of a `float` / to request rounding down to the next integer, http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/floor.xml - that said, the cast would most likely work.

Comment: @Aki So where does your first comment go in the shader? I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to implement what you've described to generate this exact pattern. Also, what happens if the pattern is non-square? I also need to do this same thing to a 3x9 texture here: http://i.imgur.com/h6ZckNE.png

Comment: @Aki I tried your complete shader and it just draws solid red. Any ideas?

Comment: It means most likely, that the texture coordinates received by the fragment are between zero and one. How have you setup them and do you use 'wrap' attribute in the sampler? For testing purposes you can try to multiply them as: `a=((int)(vTexCoord.x * 64.0))) - 3*((int)(vTexCoord.y*64.0)));` inside the fragment shader.

Comment: @Aki Ah, that's what it was. Thanks for all the help!